# fontWeight: 'bold' does not work for TextInput in react native

Tags: react-native

I have this TextInput:

```
       <TextInput
        style={styles.secondaryTitle}
        onChangeText={(skillCategory) => this.setState({skillCategory})}
        value={this.state.skillCategory}
        editable={this.props.editMode ? true : false}
      />
```

with a style of:

```
 secondaryTitle: {
    fontSize: TITLE_SECONDARY,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: COLOR_DARK_PRIMARY,
  },
```

The `fontSize` is shown correctly but it does not appear to be `bold`. I have searched around but haven't seen anyone else with the same issue. Anything I'm doing wrong here?

I have also used `secondaryTitle` for a `Text` component and it appears to be bold. I have attached screenshots below:

`TextInput`:
[image]

`Text`:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to check inspect element if style is adding properly?

Comment: Hi I just checked. it actually has the property of `fontWeight: bold` but still it does not appear to be bold

Comment: it should works, nothing wrongs there. What value of  `COLOR_DARK_PRIMARY` ? Color maybe can affect the value.

Comment: This is a known issue within react-native, and it's being discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7070) as of a couple days ago

Comment: @RyanTurnbull `fontWeight` on `TextInput` is working for me on RN 0.49.3

Comment: @IPutuYogaPermana  COLOR_DARK_PRIMARY = '#4E5161'; I doubt if this will be the problem because I also used `secondaryTitle`  for a `Text` component, and it appears to be `bold`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this problem only occurs with `multiline={false}` (which is the default).
change `multiline={false}` to `multiline={true}` or add `multiline={true}`

Comment: As noted in the comments, the `fontWeight` style prop does work in new RN versions, and no such workarounds seem necessary.

Comment: I would consider looking into other sources of this problem in your case, as for default system fonts, the `fontWeight` prop works as intended. Hopefully that will not be a waste of your time.